# jQuery previous sibling question

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the exact difference between jQuery prev() and :prev ?

I mean in terms of what they accept, return...I am asking this question as I had got an error earlier when i tried to add a $() selector after that..

Comment: `:prev` is only a valid selector if you add it to jQuery (through a plugin or your own code). Otherwise, it's just a string that happens to begin with a colon character, and an error will be raised if you try to use it as a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.prev()`is a method which you can call on any jquery object associated to a dom element. It will find the prev sibling element. If we pass selector to`prev` method it will find the prev sibling only if the selector matches.

Comment: E.g `$("#mydiv")` is a jquery object associated to `mydiv`. When you  say `$("mydiv").prev()` it will return you the first previous `sibling` of `mydiv`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't think `:prev` was a valid jQuery selector.  Could be the cause of your error.